# Making a single pointer point to an array of pointers and pass for both C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a struct like this one:

```
struct foo
{
    IBar* ptr;
};
```

which is part of a foo object with a long lifetime. Users often get instances of those objects in different callbacks and sometimes they inject stuff into the IBar* in certain places, use it in later callbacks, free it eventually. (IBar has `virtual void free() { delete this; }` which can be overridden of course).

The problem is I want to transition my users to the possibility of having more than one `IBar*` per foo struct and I want to make the transition smooth. One idea for making the transition smooth is changing the foo struct as follows:

```
struct foo
{
    foo()
    {
        ptr = reinterpret_cast<IBar*>(new IBar*[N]);
        memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(IBar*)*N);
    }

    IBar*& getBarPtr(size_t offset)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<IBar**>(ptr)[offset];
    }

    IBar* ptr;
};
```

My idea is that this way, anyone using the old style where they expect there to be only one `IBar*` should fallback on using the first of the `N` transparently in the usual way of using it:

```
someFoo.ptr = new iImplementIBar(...);
```

but those users who begin to transition to new usage can get their offset and instead do

```
someFoo.getBarPtr(myOffset) = new iImplementIBar(...);
```

the problem, though, is that `foo` had a `reset` method which used to do this:

```
void reset() {
    if (ptr)
    {
        ptr->free();
        ptr = 0;
    }
}
```

which this idea replaces with this:

```
void reset() {
    IBar** ptrs = reinterpret_cast<IBar*>(ptr);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
         if (ptrs[i])
        {
            ptrs[i]->free();
            ptrs[i] = 0;
        }
}
```

and the functionality of the `free` in the above seems to be lost. Is there a way to make this work? Or what goes wrong?

Comment: This is just gross. Why not try out more modern C++ constructs, like `std::vector<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>`?

Comment: -1 for offensive content (i suspect general trolling).

Comment: The idea is to eventually move it to a legit double pointer where it can be clean. As ugly as the above looks..it is only supposed to be a temporary transition and the point is for it to be as transparent as possible to the users of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* must do this without implementing a newer interface, why not have something like this:

```
struct foo
{
    IBar **bars; // or better yet: std::array or std::vector if size of N is fixed.
    IBar *ptr;

    IBar *getBar(int index)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
};
```

That way users of the existing 'foo' interface continue to use `ptr` but the new `bars` interface is also available for those who wish to use it.

Without knowing more it's hard to know whether the above design makes sense.

Comment: This is what I did originally...and eventually the above idea would move to this and IBar* would disappear altogether. The above "hack" was just me wondering if there was a way to make one IBar* work for both use cases despite how ugly it looked and only during the transition time.

Answer (score 0):

Without recommending using this complicated and manual lifetime management design, it is possible to build a dummy IBar that will forward to the first IBar in the set while freeing the whole set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

// existing:
struct IBar
{
    virtual void method() =0;
    virtual void free() =0;
};

struct Bar : public IBar
{
    virtual void method() { }
    virtual void free() { delete this; }
};

struct foo
{
    virtual void reset() { if (ptr) {ptr->free();}}
    IBar* ptr;
};

// proposed:
struct fooset;

struct foosetwrap : public IBar
{
    virtual void method();
    virtual void free();
    fooset* ptrOwner;
};

struct fooset : public foo
{
    fooset(IBar** begin, IBar** end) : ptrBegin(begin) , ptrEnd(end) 
        { wrapper.ptrOwner = this; ptr = &wrapper; }
    IBar** begin(){return ptrBegin;}
    IBar** end(){return ptrEnd;}
    virtual void reset() {for(auto& expired : *this) { if (!!expired) { expired->free(); }}}
private:
    foosetwrap wrapper;
    IBar** ptrBegin;
    IBar** ptrEnd;
};

void foosetwrap::method() { (*(ptrOwner->begin()))->method(); }
void foosetwrap::free() { ptrOwner->reset(); }

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    IBar* bars[]={new(std::nothrow) Bar(),new(std::nothrow) Bar()};

    fooset set(std::begin(bars), std::end(bars));
    set.ptr->method();
    set.ptr->free();
    return 0;
}
```